# Cordova issue can't add platform android

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, cordova-3

```
C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm>cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.example.hello" at location "C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Download complete

C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm>cd hello

C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello>cordova platform add android
'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello>
```

Comment: Is cordova part of your path? Where is cordova installed? If it is in C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm then it will be because it cannot find the cordova binary in the folder C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm\hello and this can be solved by amending your path...

Comment: hey tom can you please explain more, i mean cordova binary? and amending path?

Comment: The cordova binary will be the cordova executable or batch file that is executed when you run the command cordova, the path is where the operating system looks for such executable files if they are not located in the current directory.

Comment: so do you mean i have to copy cordova.batch file and copy in my-app folder created by cordova?

Comment: No, actually npm install -g cordova as suggested in the answer by Amit Gupta should automatically solve this, as the cli files installed globally by npm should be automatically available everywhere.

Comment: its not taking globally i think thats the issue

Comment: Hmmm that's strange, have you installed global modules before with npm, it could be a permissions issue? Otherwise, find the cordova file and add its directory to your path.

Comment: Path as in in environment variables?

Comment: yes it worked i added the path in environement variable

Answer (score 2):

**Before running any command-line tools**, you need to install SDKs for each platform you wish to target. Say **Android**

To install the cordova command-line tool, follow these steps:

Download and install [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Following installation, you should be able to invoke node or npm on your command line.

Install the cordova utility. In Unix, prefixing the additional sudo command may be necessary to install development utilities in otherwise restricted directories:

```
 For Mac $ sudo npm install -g cordova

 For Windows >npm install -g cordova
```

once successful installation of cordova is done ,now you can create your application

across all the platforms.

**Create the Cordova Application**

Go to the directory where you maintain your source code, and run a command such as the following:

```
 $cordova create hello com.example.hello CordovaDemo
```

**hello** is the directory where you want to create your application

**com.example.hello** is the package name

**CordovaDemo** is the name of the Application

**Add Platforms**

All subsequent commands need to be run within the project's directory, or any sub directories within its scope:

```
 $ cd hello
```

Then

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have already done this steps but as u can see that cordova gets extracted in C:\Users\pratik.agrawal\AppData\Roaming\npm> and from here i am trying to build my app which create the app folder and all the files but i am not able to add platform by chenging directory to my created app, please check above commands u will understand

Comment: @user2822117 use command line tool for installing the Cordova first.

Comment: yes its already done, so i am able to create my app, the problem is i cannot add platform in my-app directory because there is not cordova. batch file in my-app directory, but the point is how do i do it now hosuld i copy batch file of cordova and paste it

Answer (score 2):

For people visiting this question from google, the specific problem here was that after the global install from npm, the cordova binary was not visible in other directories. The path to the directory where cordova was installed had to be manually added to the path (see comments on OP).

Answer (score 0):

This is a **Unresolved cordova** bug already posted in jira -platform add android fails on Mac with JAVA_HOME error. check this 
***https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5422***

Comment: hi is this bug applicable in windows 7?